# Is it right about an example of bilinear map $e$?

Tags: elliptic-curves

The equation for the elliptic curve is $y^{2} = x^{3} + x$ and is defined over the field $F_{q}$ for some prime $q\equiv 3 \pmod 4$, and set $q=307$. Choose random generator $g=[182, 240]$. My question is that how do I construct a bilinear map $e$ and compute $g_{1} = e(g, g)$?

Comment: $g$ has order $77$, this is probably not what you want.

Comment: In general, this curve is bad because the largest prime factor of the order of its group is $11$. You want a point of large prime order.

Comment: Yes, I know. I am just wondering how to construct a bilinear map e?

Comment: I am currently writing a detailed answer, but using a different curve from yours.

Comment: Okay, Could you please send me the detailed answer? many thanks.

Comment: I will post it here. ;)

Answer (score 4):

The simplest construction that I know of is given in Section 6.9 of [the book by Hoffstein, Pipher and Silverman](http://www.springer.com/jp/book/9781493917105) (5.9 in the first edition). I also talk about it in Section 3.3 of [this](http://fkraiem.org/PER.pdf) (but I do not claim that it matches the book's quality of exposition).

First, you need a prime $p$ with two properties:

- You want $p\equiv 2\pmod 3$, this allows you to easily construct a supersingular curve over $\mathbf{F}_p$ (as $Y^2 = X^3 + b$ for any $b \ne 0$). Remember that a supersingular curve is one which has $p+1$ points.
- You want $p+1$ to have a large prime factor, ideally $q = (p+1)/6$ should be prime. This allows you to pick a point of large prime order. In fact, it is best to first choose a prime $q$ of appropriate size, and then look for a suitable $p$.

For this example, I take $p = 587$ and $b = 1$. Then $q = (p+1)/6 = 137$ is prime, and the point $P = [332,103]$ has order $q$ on the curve $E$ with equation $Y^2 = X^3 + 1$ over $\mathbf{F}_p$. I note $E(K)$ the goup of points of $E$ with coordinates in $K$ ($K$ will be either $\mathbf{F}_p$ or $\mathbf{F}_{p^2}$.)

The basic tool is the [Weil pairing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_pairing), which I will note $e_q$. All you need to know about it is that it is a bilinear map from the group of $q$-torsion points of the curve (*i.e.*, the group of points $P$ such that $qP = \infty$) to the group of $q$th roots of unity in $\mathbf{F}_p$ (*i.e.*, the group of all $x\in \mathbf{F}_p$ such that $x^q = 1$). You can use many computer algebra systems to compute the Weil pairing, I use [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/):

```
gp > p = 821;
gp > p%3
2
gp > isprime(p)
1
gp > q = (p+1)/6
137
gp > isprime(q)
1
gp > E = ellinit([0,1]*Mod(1,p));
gp > until(ellorder(E,P) == q, P = random(E));
gp > P
[Mod(332, 821), Mod(103, 821)]
gp > ellweilpairing(E,P,P,q)
Mod(1, 821)
```

However, the Weil pairing is not suitable as is for cryptographic purposes because it is also *alternating*, meaning that $e_q(P,P) = 1$ for all $P$, so we need to modify it. What we do is consider the curve as being defined over $\mathbf{F}_{p^2}$, and apply the Weil pairing in this curve. More precisely, it we let $\zeta$ be a primitive $3$rd root of unity in $\mathbf{F}_{p^2}$ (prove that it exists), then for any point $P = [x_P,y_P] \in E(\mathbf{F}_p)$, the point $P' = [\zeta\cdot x_P,y_P]$ is in $E(\mathbf{F}_{p^2})$. Moreover, if $qP = \infty$, then $qP' = \infty$ as well, which means that $P'$ can be an "argument" of $e_q$. Hence, finally, we define our "modified Weil pairing" $\hat{e}_q$ on the original curve (over $\mathbf{F}_p$) as follows: for a point $Q = kP$ (for some integer $k$), we let
$$\hat{e}_q(P,Q) = e_q(P,Q'),$$
where $e_q$ is the ordinary Weil pairing, but applied on the curve over $\mathbf{F}_{p^2}$. In practice:

```
gp > u = ffgen(p^2, u);
gp > until(z != 1, z = random(u)^((p^2-1)/3));
gp > E2 = ellinit([0,1],u);
gp > ellmodweilpairing(E,P,Q,q) = ellweilpairing(E2,P,[z*Q[1],Q[2]],q);
gp > ellmodweilpairing(E,P,P,q)
562*u + 172
```

We can see that this pairing is bilinear:

```
gp > Q = ellmul(E,P,99);
gp > ellmodweilpairing(E,P,P,q)*ellmodweilpairing(E,P,Q,q)
693*u + 108
gp > ellmodweilpairing(E,P,elladd(E,P,Q),q)
693*u + 108
```

Comment: +1, although it would be nice a brief explanation of how the Weil pairing is constructed, which was one of OP's questions.

Comment: I agree, but sadly I don't know any (and yes, this makes my answer not entirely satisfactory).

Comment: Chapter 5.1 from [here](http://www.craigcostello.com.au/pairings/PairingsForBeginners.pdf) seems to give a simple example of the Weil pairing. I don't have the background to fully understand it, but maybe you could spell it out for the rest of us :)
Maybe it could be more interesting if I ask a new question regarding this?